# area of the parallelogram with 1-forms

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\omega$ and $v$ be $1$-forms on $T_p\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $\omega \wedge v(V_1,V_2)$ is the area of the parallelogram spanned by $V_1$ and $V_2$, times the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\left\langle \omega \right\rangle$ and $\left\langle v \right\rangle$.

Suppose that $\omega=adx+bdy+cdz$ and $v=a_1dx+b_1dy+c_1z$. Then

$\omega\wedge v=(adx+bdy+cdz)(a_1dx+b_1dy+c_1z)=(bc_1-cb_1)dy\wedge dz-(ac_1-a_1c)dz\wedge dx+(ab_1-ba_1)dx\wedge dy$

Hence
$\omega\wedge v(V_1,V_2)=(bc_1-cb_1)dy\wedge dz(V_1,V_2)-(ac_1-a_1c)dz\wedge dx(V_1,V_2)+(ab_1-ba_1)dx\wedge dy(V_1,V_2)=(bc_1-cb_1)\begin{vmatrix} dy(V_1) & dy(V_2)\\ dz(V_1) & dz(V_2)\end{vmatrix}-(ac_1-a_1c)\begin{vmatrix} dz(V_1) & dz(V_2)\\ dx(V_1) & dx(V_2)\end{vmatrix}+(ab_1-ba_1)\begin{vmatrix} dx(V_1) & dx(V_2)\\ dy(V_1) & dy(V_2)\end{vmatrix} $

How I can guarantee that this is the the area of the parallelogram spanned by $V_1$ and $V_2$, times the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\left\langle \omega \right\rangle$ and $\left\langle v \right\rangle$.Where $\left\langle \omega \right\rangle=\left\langle a,b,c \right\rangle$ and $\left\langle v \right\rangle=\left\langle a_1,b_1,c_1 \right\rangle$

Comment: you are wrong considering that $\omega,\nu$ have three components, instead you should consider them as $\omega=adx+bdy$ and $\nu=pdx+qdy$ (write avoiding indexing 'cuz causes less confusion)

Answer (score 0):

With the clarification your calculations are

\begin{eqnarray*}
\omega\wedge v(V_1,V_2)&=&(aq-bp)dx\wedge dy(V_1,V_2)\\
&=&(aq-bp)\begin{vmatrix}dx(V_1)&dx(V_2)\\dy(V_1)&dy(V_2)\end{vmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}